# C# problem read text from excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I tried to read an Excel file using OLEDB.
I can read the integers correctly, but the problem occurs when I want to read text.

I also tried IMEX=1 but it didn't work!

Here is my sample code:

```
connectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes'");

adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet + "$]", connectionString);

DataSet data= new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(data);
```

Comment: Do you get an error? If, so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

This might help although I havent run into this issue before setting IMEX = 1

Setting IMEX=1 tells the driver to use Import mode. In this state, the registry setting ImportMixedTypes=Text will be noticed. This forces mixed data to be converted to text. For this to work reliably, you may also have to modify the registry setting, TypeGuessRows=8. The ISAM driver by default looks at the first eight rows and from that sampling determines the datatype. If this eight row sampling is all numeric, then setting IMEX=1 will not convert the default datatype to Text; it will remain numeric.

You must be careful that IMEX=1 not be used indiscriminately. This is IMPORT mode, so the results may be unpredictable if you try to do appends or updates of data in this mode.

The possible settings of IMEX are:
        0 is Export mode
        1 is Import mode
        2 is Linked mode (full update capabilities)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194124

Answer (score 0):

use

```
connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + file + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text""";
```

This should help when reading but be careful if you want to write - IMEX=1 says this is import mode and writing with this setting yields unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem while reading .XLSX and here is what I provided in connection string and it worked.

`connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text""";`

Answer (score -1):

Try inserting 5 dummy rows on the first 5 row of your excel sheet. 
This way, all the consecutive rows will be identified as Strings. You can further do your data type conversions.
Then remove the 5 dummy rows on the code.

Comment: This may or may not work, but my guess is that the OP wants to be able to read excel files programmatically, without having to edit them by hand first.

Comment: I understand, it is an Excel hell. I was in it recently. I basically had to convert my xlsx. file to Tab delimited text so that SSIS can read it correctly. Adding dummy rows(if you can) is not a handsome solution but does work.